# Entity Framework Code First - Table Per Hierarchy - should the Discriminator field be indexed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Quite simply, when using Code First and creating a table per hierarchy table my gut feeling is that the `Discriminator` field should be indexed as it'll be used to filter the data with pretty much every query.

Why doesn't EF add an Index to the `Discriminator` field?

Answer (score 1):

Not always. You can find some people talking about this here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4030.

Now, if you judge that will be better to create an index, you can use the convention delivery in the `nuget Package EntityFramework.DiscriminatorIndex` as described here: https://bytenosso.blogspot.com.br/2016/10/entity-framework-discriminator-index.html

Answer (score 0):

i dont know i got your question right or not but its the default behaviour of ef. In the TPH mapping scenario,all types in an inheritance hierarchy are mapped to a single table.  A discriminator column is used to identify the type of each row. When creating your model with Code First, TPH is the default strategy for the types that participate in the inheritance hierarchy.
and you modify this behaviour using Fluent Api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()  
.Map<Course>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Course"))  
.Map<OnsiteCourse>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("OnsiteCourse"));
```

Comment: Not quite what I was asking, I understand that the discriminator column is there to distinguish between the classes mapped to the single table. What I would expect is for that column to be indexed, as pretty much every single query to that table will be using the discriminator column as part of the where clause.

Comment: are you interested to use the discriminator value itself? the discriminator column is used internally by Code First and you cannnot read/write its values from an inheritance mapping standpoint.

Comment: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) this blog post is very helpful to understand the concept of discriminator column.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand the purpose of the discriminator column. My question is should it be indexed. By default, Code First does not index this column.

Comment: youre right but as much as i know this wasnt the point of tph, tph is a basic inheritance model which ef uses when it finds inheritance in classes and if anyone wants to have more advanced access to inherited classes tpt is a better strategy.